# Why if $a<b$ and $-a<b$ we can say that $|a|<b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Why if $a<b$ and $-a<b$, then we can say that $|a|<b$?

Maybe this is trivial by I don't know how to proof it.

Comment: You've been asking a lot of questions in a rather short time, all centered around absolute values and modules. Maybe it would be better if you made one longer, organized question. It would show us where the question comes from, what you already know, etc

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but have you actually tried to look for the answer online?

Comment: @AinzOoalGoal You're right but I'm not doing this intentionally. The problem is that this is not explained or even mentioned in my book. Pleas if you know a very good book that explains these topics (Absolute Value and Complex Numbers), just say me :)

Comment: @GniruT Why don't you join me in [the maths chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) ? That way you'll be able to ask those small questions without creating many separate threads :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $a \geq 0$, then $|a| = a$; so $a < b$ implies $|a| < b$.

If $a < 0$, then $|a| = -a$; so $-a < b$ implies $|a| < b$.

Comment: This is a good explanation, with its clear separation into the two cases.

Answer (score 4):

We have either $|a|=a$ or $|a|=-a$, hence what you wrote holds

Answer (score 3):

*One option:*

Note that $|a| = \max(a, -a)$. Hence if $a < b$ and $-a < b$, then

$$\max(a, -a) < b$$

That is

$$|a| < b$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose not, and show it contradicts your hypotheses.

Note that $|a|$ is either $a$ or $-a$.

In the first case, you would have $a\geq b$, contrary to the hypothesis $a<b$.

In the second case, you would have $-a\geq b$, contrary to the hypothesis that $-a<b$.

In either case, the supposition that the result is false leads to a contradiction of the hypotheses. Therefore, the hypotheses imply that the result is true, *quod erat demonstrandum.*

Comment: This is a completely useless use of proof by contradiction.  You should always try to avoid contradiction when you can.

Comment: @Donkey_2009: That's not only unnecessarily harsh, it's also incorrect.

Comment: Sorry - I see now that I used unnecessarily harsh language.  It's not incorrect though - see any of the other answers for a contradiction-free proof.